# Does CI page caching include both data & page?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, caching

I'm setting up the foundation for an application with a rapidly expanding database. Currently with only around 12000 users there's already a table with over 5 million record fields. This is starting to up the times queries in get executed a lot. Therefore I started thinking about caching either queries or the entire pages for a limited time (say 30 minutes, maybe an hour).

I've read up a lot about the caching options of CodeIgniter (v2.1.4) throughout the user-guide ([here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html), [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html) and [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#caching) for example) and throughout a bunch of forums and SO questions about caching.

I also read up a little bit about Memcached and APC methods of caching. Based on comments and differences I'd like to use [APC Caching](https://www.php.net/apc).

So, does caching a page also include all of the data required to make up the page content? Or do the queries get executed each time a cached page is to be served up?

If the latter, how can I cache the query results for a limited time (say the before mentioned 30 or 60 minutes) to prevent the database becoming too busy?

The preferred situation would be to be able to store complete pages and have them refreshed (also without a user request for the page) every time a timer runs down. The page would of course include new data from a query as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CI-intern general caching ( http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html ) using `$this->output->cache(n);` does cache the whole output (and only works if you use `$this->load->view`). 
The problem is, that the user-related content is cached too and delivered to other users. I got my experience with this...

You can take a look at the detailled caching-lib http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html. If your question was related to this library anyway, I cannot help you unfortunately.

Comment: Just to clarify that I understand you correctly. If user X with rights to M on page userdata, the same page/data gets served to user Y with rights to P on page userdata?

Comment: Yes, user Y gets the cached output of user X. This were my experiences with the general CI-caching. Maybe I did something wrong, but it was nearly only one line of code I've added... 
You can maybe try it on localhost. Login with user X go to users profile-page (with `$this->output->caching(5);`) or whatever, then logout and login with user Y, go to profile page.

Comment: I guess you could do like `->save("user_profile_{$user_id}", $result, 1200)`, and it get's unique per user?

Comment: Could you give an example @RobinCastlin ? I would like to know how you would go about doing that.

Comment: Well, basically you save a string unique per user by supplying the user_id into the string? Example already given. All official data wouldn't use this, of course.